How to apply rounded corners to an image loaded with Coil's SubcomposeAsyncImage using ContentScale.Fit in an Android Compose App?
I'm working on an Android Compose app and using Coil's SubcomposeAsyncImage to load images asynchronously. I want to apply rounded corners to these images while ensuring they maintain their aspect ratio using ContentScale.Fit. The images should also be maximally large.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
Column(
    modifier =
        modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Cyan),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
) {
    SubcomposeAsyncImage(
        modifier =
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .background(Color.Blue),
        model = model.build(),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
        contentDescription = null,
        loading = {},
        error = {},
    )
}

For example when I use this test image:

I get this result:

So the RoundedCornerShape is not applied to the image but only to the container holding the image. How can I get around that?

fyi left an answer below - keen to hear if that's sorted it out for ya!

The main cause of the issue is that the .fillMaxSize() modifier will use all the available space. Instead, you want the image to only use as much height as necessary after scaling the image up to fill the maximum available width.
Unfortunately, there is no combination of modifiers available to determine that height. Instead you have to give it a clue by specifying either

An aspect ratio to maintain
A specific size to use

Here's an example using Image, as the issue isn't unique to Coil's SubcomposeAsyncImage
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        // using aspect ratio
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.test_image),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(40.dp))
        )

        // using size
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.test_image),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(400.dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(40.dp))
        )
    }

It might be possible to use a Coil Interceptor or do some measurements to dynamically compute the aspect ratio of any image. In the meantime, I don't know any other way to do it without already knowing the aspect ration OR having a specific size or aspect ratio you want.
